# Maximum Area between 2 curves

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

For which  value of $a$ the area bound by function $y = m(x -a)$ (upper limit) and function $y = x^{3} -1$(lower limit) from $b$ to $-2b$ will be maximum ?
If the maximum area is $"R"$ then show that $ R = \frac{27}{4} $

In the beginning of this problem we have to prove 
             $$ a= \frac{2b^{3}}{3b^{2} -1} $$ $$m = 3b^{2} -1$$
so...those data can be also used in this problem ...

Here's what i did ,
           first i took an expresion for $ R$  $$ \int_{b}^{-2b} \mathrm m(x-a) - [x^{3} -x] \mathrm{d}x $$and... after a long simplification i end up with $$ R = \frac{27}{4}b^{4} $$
then i  differentiate it.. $$\frac{dR}{db} = 27b^{3} ----(1)$$
then...
$$ a= \frac{2b^{3}}{3b^{2} -1} $$and $$ \frac{db}{da} = \frac{(3b^{2}-1)^{2} }{6b^{2}(b^{2}-1)}-----(2)$$
              and finally...$$\frac{dR}{da} = \frac{dR}{db} . \frac{db}{da}$$
so...from (1) and (2) I end up with $$ \frac {dR}{da} = \frac{9b(3b^{2}-1)^{2}}{2(b^{2}-1)} $$
after that what i think was... if i can find the $b$ values where $\frac{dR}{da} = 0$ then through that i could find the maximums and minimums of this function which will lead me to the finale answer....

but after that i could never get the value $R = \frac{27}{4}$ which means my method is wrong...

Iwould be glad if anyone can give me some advice to me about this and show me what was my mistake :)
Thanks in advance :)